# display link to a custom plugin in admin menu bar

Tags: plugins

i have a custom plugin and i want the link to the plugin be accessible in the **admin menu bar** of the `wp-admin`

right now, im using below code. but the link to this shows under my settings. what hook should i replace with the `add_option_page`?

```
function custom_plugin() {
    add_options_page("my plugin", "plugin settings", 1, "my plugin", "custom_function");
}

add_action ('admin_menu', 'custom_plugin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add a top level menu page then you need to use `add_menu_page()` function more details on [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'my plugin', 'plugin settings', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_custom_function', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 66 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

basic structure is:

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, 
$function, $icon_url, $position );
```

See example

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page() {
  add_menu_page( 'Custom Menu Page Title', 'Custom Menu Page', 'manage_options', 'custom.php', '', 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus', 90 );
}
```